# How to recursively search for files starting with ".#" under a path in zsh?

Tags: regex, zsh, find

In the current working directory, `la -a` returns,

```
.              .#program 2.py .DS_Store      picker.py
.#picker 2.py  .#program 3.py hw1            temp.test
.#picker.py    ..             hw2
```

I tried `find . -type f -name '.*' -print` to find all the dot files which works.

But when I try `find . -type f -name '.#*' -print`, that does not print out anything.

I am not very good with shells, could someone help?

Comment: Does it work if you `unsetopt EXTENDED_GLOB` before this, or escape the hash? e.g. `'.\#*'` I think in ZSH, `#` is interpreted as a special character due to the extended globbing features.

Comment: Neither of those made a difference. I ran the escaped version before and after `unsetopt EXTENDED_GLOB`. BTW, for what it is worth, I also tried running "bash" and trying out the commands in the bash shell and they still don't show anything.

Comment: It works perfectly fine for me both on zsh and bash, with the same file names. You should provide more details, such as system + version, zsh/bash versions, if you tried with default configs, etc.

Comment: I am on MacOS Sonoma `14.0 (23A344)`. How do I check the zsh version? I did not really change any default settings.